# pandas pivot multiple values for index

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I have been struggling how to use pivot function.

I am trying to make the index as flat_type.

When I tried to use the pivot function, I kept getting this error:

```
TypeError: pivot() got multiple values for argument 'index'
```

And I have no idea how to fix it.

Any help or suggesttion would do greatly.! thankyou have a nice day!

link to dataset: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/median-rent-by-town-and-flat-type

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('median-rent-by-town-and-flat-type (1).csv',na_values=['na','-'])

mydf = df.dropna()

mydf = mydf.reset_index()

mydf.pivot(mydf,index="flat_type",columns="town",values="median_rent")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `mydf` from `pivot` in paratheses, because already chained `mydf` with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) method:

```
mydf.pivot(index="flat_type",columns="town",values="median_rent")
```

Another solution is use [`pandas.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) - then is changed `mydf.pivot` to `pd.pivot`:

```
pd.pivot(mydf, index="flat_type",columns="town",values="median_rent")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my removing df

```
mydf.pivot(index="flat_type", columns="town", values="median_rent")
```

Thank you.

Comment: now it says 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
'

Comment: im confused, why cant an index with duplicate entires reshape